# PNaCl local server build error on Windows [ppapi_ALL_TARGET] Error 2

Tags: windows, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I'm learning to develop a web-application with the google-nativeclient on a windows platform (win7). according to the instructions i must run `make serve` from the `src` directory of the pepper_(VERSION) I installed with the SDK, which in my case is pepper_31. The build runs until it gets to a point where it fails and show the following message:

**

```
C:/bin/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/tools/host_vc.mk:25: *** Unable to find cl.exe in PATH while building Windows host build.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/bin/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/src/ppapi'
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/bin/nacl_sdk/nacl_sdk/pepper_31/src/ppapi'
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'ppapi_ALL_TARGET' failed
make: *** [ppapi_ALL_TARGET] Error 2
```

**

I figured its missing the cl.exe program but i don't even know what that is and how to get it. Can anyone help with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should have been a message before error:

```
To skip the host build use:
"make NO_HOST_BUILDS=1"
```

So the quick answer is: no, you don't need cl.exe (it is the Visual Studio C compiler) as long as you run `make NO_HOST_BUILDS=1 <target>`.

You can also install [Visual C++ Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs), and run `make` from a Visual Studio Command Prompt; this will put `cl.exe` in your path, so this error will go away.

Either way, this is not a great experience -- I've filed [this bug](http://crbug.com/320770) to track this issue.

Comment: `make NO_HOST_BUILDS=1` does not work... but i used the Visual C++ Express approach and it works. Thank you.